# How to print main diagonal of matrix and how to fill matrix with random numbers

Tags: c, matrix, random, cycle

I have matrix `a[i][j]` for example `i = j = d` (for example `3`) . How can I fill it with random numbers and then I need to show main diagonal and another diagonal over and below matrix. Almost all examples that I found were for c++ but I need to do it in C.

I thought about `cycle` but I don't know how to use it. According to my idea it should take point `a[0][0]` and `i = 0`, `i++` , `i < d` and `j=0`, `j++`  ,`j < d`. This will be main diagonal. And another one is `i = d` , `i--`, `j=0` , `j++` . Therefore it will take both diagonals and then print it though `printf`

It should look like this

```
1  6  11 16  - main diagonal

13 10 7  4   - additional diagonal
```

---

```
1  2   3   4

5  6   7   8

9  10  11  12  - random matrix

13 14  15  16
```

---

```
1  6  11  16 - main diagonal

13 10 7   4  - additional diagonal
```

Comment: use looping and rand?

Comment: These diagonals have actual names, and you should use them. ["Main diagonal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal) is fine, but I have never heard the other diagonal you reference called "additional diagonal". Secondary diagonal, minor diagonal,....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that populates a square matrix with random numbers, and then stores the primary and secondary diagonals in two arrays. These two arrays are filled at the same time in a single loop. Then the program displays the contents of each of the three arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t d = 4;
    int a[d][d];
    int primary[d], secondary[d];
    size_t i, j;

    srand(time(NULL));

    /* Fill array with random numbers */
    for (i = 0; i < d; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < d; j++)
            a[i][j] = rand() % 100;

    /* Store diagonals */
    for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        primary[i] = a[i][i];
        secondary[i] = a[d - (i + 1)][i];
        }

    /* Display arrays */
    puts("2d Array:");
    for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < d; j++) {
            printf("%-5d", a[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');

    puts("Primary Diagonal:");
    for (i = 0; i < d; i++)
        printf("%-5d", primary[i]);
    printf("\n\n");

    puts("Secondary Diagonal:");
    for (i = 0; i < d; i++)
        printf("%-5d", secondary[i]);
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a sample run:

```
2d Array:
65   59   91   10   
17   25   19   44   
94   77   68   21   
91   76   18   19   

Primary Diagonal:
65   25   68   19   

Secondary Diagonal:
91   77   19   10
```

Comment: this one worked but only when i added #define d 4 after sizet_t d =4

Comment: @PAPAmidNIHGT-- I don't understand why that would be.... I just copied and tested this from the above code, and it compiles (gcc file.c -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic) without errors or warnings on my machine and runs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you wish to print the diaganols of a square matrix with a certain number of rows/cols?

```
// You could put this code in main() or another function
int z = 3; /* z here represents the number of rows/cols in the square matrix
int matrix[z][z];
int i = 0, j = 0;
srand(time(0)); /* Part of stdlib.h and time.h; this will suffice for pur purposes */
// Fix matrix with random values
for (; i < z; ++i) {
  for (j = 0; j < z; ++i) {
    matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100; /* Part of stdlib.h; use % with rand to keep it within a certain range */
  }
}
// Print matrix
for (i = 0; i < z; ++i) {
  for (j = 0; j < z; ++j) {
    printf("%i", matrix[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
// Print top-left to bottom right diagonal
for (i = 0; i < z; ++i) {
  printf("%i", matrix[i][i]); /* Part of stdio.h */
}
printf("\n");
// Print other diagonal
for (i = z - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  printf("%i", matrix[i][z - (i + 1)]);
}
```

To explain how this works, it first declares a few variables. I chose z to represent the number of columns and rows but the name matters not. (Technically, z could be const and that might be a good idea.) Matrix is declared as `int matrix[z][z]`; what this simply means is that matrix consists of z rows and z columns. The last declaration of variables i and j are used for looping variables.

The next thing it does is seed the random numbers generator using `srand()`. `srand()` and `rand()` are both defined in the header stdlib.h. The seed is not chosen automaticalky; in this case, we're using `time()` from time.h to seed it. Then, the program loops through the matrix and assigns it a random value using the standard library function `rand()`. Rand returns a value from 0 to RAND_MAX; use modulus (%) to restrict the range.

Everything else should be pretty much explained in the comments or self-explanatory, but note that the first argument to `printf()` is a format string (here, %i stands for an integer) which specifies how to use the additional parameters given to it.

Comment: Please check the interface to [`rand()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rand.html); it doesn't match the way you're using it.

Comment: Sorry; gonna fix that.